# Amazon api not showing price when using ASIN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I need to get the top selling books along with it's details from amazon jp.

As of now, I can get the top selling books but it only gives `ASIN` and `TITLE` for each item.

```
<TopSeller>
<ASIN>4047318752</ASIN>
<Title>艦これ白書 -艦隊これくしょん オフィシャルブック-</Title>
</TopSeller>
```

So I need to get the item's details separately. I can get the details now but there is no `PRICE` even if I include `OFFERS` and it's variations.

This is the uri I use:

```
http://webservices.amazon.co.jp/onca/xml?" .
                "Service=AWSECommerceService" .
                "&Operation=ItemLookup" .
                "&BrowseNodeId=465610" .
                "&MerchantId=Amazon" .
                "&Condition=All" .
                "&IdType=ASIN" .
                "&Availability=Available" .
                "&Version=2011-08-01" .
                "&AssociateTag=$this->associateTag" .
                "&BrowseNode=17".
                "&ItemId=$itemIds" .
                "&ResponseGroup=OfferFull";
```

This is working, it's just that the price is not getting listed, and I just omitted the other `ResponseGroup`.

If you have another idea of getting the top selling books with details and price. I'd be more than happy to see it.

As Requested by CyberMJ:

Request:

```
"http://webservices.amazon.co.jp/onca/xml?" .
            "Service=AWSECommerceService" .
            "&Operation=ItemLookup" .
            "&BrowseNodeId=465610" .
            "&MerchantId=Amazon" .
            "&Condition=All" .
            "&IdType=ASIN" .
            "&Availability=Available" .
            "&Version=2011-08-01" .
            "&AssociateTag=$this->associateTag" .
            "&BrowseNode=17".
            "&ItemId=$itemIds" .
            "&ResponseGroup=Variations";
```

Response:

```
    <ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
<OperationRequest>
<HTTPHeaders>
<Header Name="UserAgent" Value="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36"/>
</HTTPHeaders>
<RequestId>b66dda52-62bf-495e-abd5-f2f9a8d96eeb</RequestId>
<Arguments>
<Argument Name="Condition" Value="All"/>
<Argument Name="Operation" Value="ItemLookup"/>
<Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"/>
<Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="mediabooks0db-20"/>
<Argument Name="BrowseNode" Value="17"/>
<Argument Name="Version" Value="2011-08-01"/>
<Argument Name="Signature" Value="/tC4kFaeaxsvL11YLthHe09PHKUQVAxTTZrf6D8FXiw="/>
<Argument Name="Availability" Value="Available"/>
<Argument Name="MerchantId" Value="Amazon"/>
<Argument Name="ItemId" Value="B00DYKPPGM,4047318752,4103345918,4047292664,B00DYKPPGM,4758007837"/>
<Argument Name="BrowseNodeId" Value="465610"/>
<Argument Name="IdType" Value="ASIN"/>
<Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="AKIAIGEZH2RG5QKAUQ5Q"/>
<Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2013-09-19T12:04:18Z"/>
<Argument Name="ResponseGroup" Value="Variations"/>
</Arguments>
<RequestProcessingTime>0.0160898510000000</RequestProcessingTime>
</OperationRequest>
<Items>
<Request>
<IsValid>True</IsValid>
<ItemLookupRequest>
<Condition>All</Condition>
<IdType>ASIN</IdType>
<MerchantId>Deprecated</MerchantId>
<ItemId>B00DYKPPGM</ItemId>
<ItemId>4047318752</ItemId>
<ItemId>4103345918</ItemId>
<ItemId>4047292664</ItemId>
<ItemId>B00DYKPPGM</ItemId>
<ItemId>4758007837</ItemId>
<ResponseGroup>Variations</ResponseGroup>
<VariationPage>All</VariationPage>
</ItemLookupRequest>
</Request>
<Item>
<ASIN>B00DYKPPGM</ASIN>
</Item>
<Item>
<ASIN>4047318752</ASIN>
</Item>
<Item>
<ASIN>4103345918</ASIN>
</Item>
<Item>
<ASIN>4047292664</ASIN>
</Item>
<Item>
<ASIN>4758007837</ASIN>
</Item>
</Items>
</ItemLookupResponse>
```

Comment: You are using a wrong ResponseGroup. Please, have a look at this post, it's the same question and I gave an answer. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923080/why-is-itemlookup-not-returning-any-price-information-even-when-requesting-all-3/13871309#13871309

Comment: You're suggested responsegroup 'Variations' did not gave me anything but the asin in the api response. But you gave me the knowledge of the inconsistency in aws api, I upped your answer there as thanks.

Comment: Can you post both request and response (XML) here, with the 'Variations' RG set in request. Maybe the Variations response group is not available at all.

Comment: I edited the post to include what you asked.

Comment: From your request, I see that you are calling "&Operation=ItemSearch" operation, instead of "&Operation=ItemLookup". You have to call the ItemLookup operation  (as you did in your initial example) in order to fetch 'Variations' response group. Please, modify your request and post the response again.

Comment: Oh sorry bout that, I edited it again.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this behavior, but haven't had any success, although I am using (American) Amazon API. Is it possible that the problem is related to 'Amazon jp'? 
If you have account for any other amazon API, you can try to reproduce the problem. Otherwise, I cannot help you, since your request is valid.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with AZ USA, so it is not limited to jp.  The issue only happens with certain items though, likely ones that amazon offers via merchants instead of directly, (although it doesnt always happen).  I have tried a hundred variations of code and nothing seems to return the price for these items

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out, try changing your response group to

responseGroup('Large,VariationSummary')

And then get the price via

$response->Items->Item->VariationSummary->LowestPrice->Amount

Adding VariationSummary allowed me to get prices on the few items that were missing them